# Is there any way to use Consumer and Supplier interface together in a program(java 8)?

Tags: java, java-8, interface

Actually i want to create collection of String type through **Consumer** interface and want to print  that by using a **Supplier** interface...

Q:"WAP to add the Kunal, Ravi,Jeremy to a collection using Consumer interface and print all using Supplier interface. Use only lambda functions."

Comment: There's context missing. Where are the values coming from and how is something consisting of "only lambda functions" supposed to form a program? In ordinary Java, you need at least a class containing a `main` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it's possible as far as you talk about supplier running first and then consumer but vice-versa is not true.

For example, take below code

```
Supplier<List<String>> supplier = () -> Arrays.asList("Kunal", "Ravi", "Jeremy");
supplier.get().forEach(student -> System.out.println(student));
```

This works well as supplier supplied and then consumer consumed but vice-versa is not possible neither by definition nor logically.

Comment: Ok. But why would have they given me a wrong question to solve if it isn't possible to implement and execute....

Comment: I think you should consult the person who gave you the question. May be they want to test your logical java reasoning :P